# CSS: How can I set an element's position with middle as origin, from Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, css, image, alignment

I've got an image marking a scale, where the marker's position is in HTML set to be

```
<image class="red-marker" xlink:href="./assets/images/marker.png"
[attr.x]=percentage width="12"height="40" y="0" ></image>
```

However, I want the marker's middle to appear at this position. Now its left side aligns with that. See image:

[The marker's position when 'percentage' is 100%:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6iDW.png)
Is there any way in HTML, CSS or Javascript I could fix this by for example:

- Setting image origin to horizontal middle
- Using CSS's calc() on X position together with an unknown Javascript variable
- Apply position inside Javascript, refering to variable there.

?

Comment: Can you set a negative margin to one half the width of the image?

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) You can add `transform: translateX(-50%)` to the CSS of the image. This moves it to the left by half of its own width.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/fa0"></div>
```